# installed boost but still saying fatal error:boost/tokenizer.hpp: No such file or

Tags: c++, boost, g++, fatal-error

I have installed boost using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

And in my C++ code I included

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using namespace boost
```

But when I compile, it still says

```
fatal error:boost/tokenizer.hpp: No such file or Directory
```

Besides that, I also tried downloading the boost package and unziping it, then placed it inside the same directory as my C++ file. Such that I can see `test.cpp` and Folder called boost, when I click into boost, there is `tokenizer.hpp` and other `.hpp` files. It's giving the same error.

Comment: Are `boost` directories correctly added to you `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? How do you compile the code ?

Comment: Oh I didn't do anything after the Installation regarding adding path. Can you tell me how to add path?  I compiled the code using g++ test.cpp -o test   then ./test

Comment: Compile it using: `g++ -I path/to/boost test.cpp -o test`

Comment: And read paragraph of [Boost getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)